# Retrieving unexpected null from a callable statement OUT parameter

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, java-stored-procedures

I have two procedures: a java stored procedure JAVA_P() which is linked to a static method O.execute() and a pl/sql procedure SQL_P(in_param IN CUSTOM_TYPE_1, out_param OUT CUSTOM_TYPE_2).

JAVA_P calls SQL_P with CallableStatement.

And now a big WTF:
   When I run O.execute() outside oracle (from external jvm) received out_param is set as expected.
   When I run O.execute() as JAVA_P() (using oracle built-in jvm) then out_param is set to null (SQL_P is executed without exception and output parameter should be set).

Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
JRE version used for tests 1.4.2_04.
JDBC version 10.2.0.3.0

@Juergen Hartelt my english may not be good enought to explain this clearly but i will try this way:

1) i have write some java code using as usual my IDE:

```
public class P141_JAVABridge
{
   public static void execute()
   {
        String databaseDriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String databaseUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1521:orcl";
        String databaseUsername = "xxx";
        String databasePassword = "xxx";

        ods.setDriverType(databaseDriver);
        ods.setURL(databaseUrl);
        ods.setUser(databaseUsername);
        ods.setPassword(databasePassword);

        connection = ods.getConnection();


        .... some code

        map.put("custom_T",Custom_T_SQLData.class);

        CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("call P141(?,?)");

        call.setObject(1,inputObjectReference);
        call.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.STRUCT,"custom_T");
        call.execute();

        .... some code

   }
}
```

2) i run this code - wooha! it works

3) i have changed

```
connection = ods.getConnection();
```

to

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
```

4) compile and load class into oracle

5) i have linked P141_JAVABridge.execute() with P141_JB

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P141_JB () IS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'x.y.z.P141_JAVABridge.execute()';
```

6) then i executed P141_JB

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN

   ...some code

   P141_JB();

   ...some code

END;
```

and got NullPointerException at

```
((Custom_T_SQLData)call.getObject(2)).responseStatus
```

Comment: Maybe you have some tips how to debug this?

Comment: What do you mean by "received out_param"? Did you output the value from inside JAVA_P after calling SQL_P()? Or did you build some wrapper class, which outputs returned values after the call to JAVA_P()?

Comment: @JuergenHartelt I have put some details in my original post

Comment: Ah ok, I totally did not get the fact that you were encountering an exception :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done as [Tolls](http://www.java-forums.org/members/tolls.html) adviced me and I have put "call P141(?,?)" into braces:

```
"{call P141(?,?)}"
```

TADA! It works.